# How to detect the height of a table in js Autotable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to dynamically get the height of a table in a PDF that I created using jsPDF and js Autotable. I want to add a line of text under the table, but since the table height changes, I can't put a specific Y value for the text line.

My current table script:

```
let col = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3']
let rows = arrayForTable;

let getTableWidth = 150;
let pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
let tableMargin = (pageWidth - getTableWidth) / 2;
let height = 0;

doc.autoTable(col, rows, {
   margin: {top: 20, right: tableMargin, left: tableMargin},
   startY: 70,
   styles: {
      halign: 'center',
      overflow: 'linebreak',
      cellWidth: 'wrap',
      valign: 'middle'
   },
   columnStyles: {
      0: {cellWidth: 50},
      1: {cellWidth: 50},
      2: {cellWidth: 50},   
   },
   headStyles: {
      fillColor: [163, 32, 32]
   },
   didParseCell: function(data) {
      if (data.row.index === rows.length - 1) {
         data.cell.styles.fillColor = [63, 63, 64];
         data.cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold';
         data.cell.styles.textColor = [255, 255, 255];
      }
      height = data.table.height
   }
});

console.log(height)
```

The console prints undefined. Anyone know how to dynamically add a line of text under this table without having to designate a static Y value like this:

```
doc.text(25, 40, exampleText);
```

The table height changes every time because of different data being shown.

I am using jsPDF AutoTable plugin v3.5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Get the cursor position on Y axis using

> didDrawPage

which will be precisely after the table.
This worked for me in Angular 2:

```
let yPos = 0;
pdf.autoTable({
    ...
    didDrawPage: function(data) {
        yPos = data.cursor.y;
    }
}
```

jspdf version:

> "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
>
> "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.14",

Source:
[Table height is always 0 #604](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/604)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to add the text under the table. Instead of trying to read the table height, you can read the last cell Y position. What you need to do is like this

```
let height = 0;
....
didParseCell: function(data) {
      ...
      height = data.cursor.y + data.row.height;
   }
....
```

then you can adjust the position of the text you want to add, for the example I want to add `10` gap between the table and the text

```
doc.text("exampleText", 25, height + 10);
```